# Angular: selected on option of select doesn't work as excepted while using along with ngModel

Tags: angular, typescript

I have an array of objects(named **users**) which will be shown as options of `dropdownlist`. and I have another objects list(named **selectedUsers** and is saved in backend) which is used to initialize the `dropdownlist`.

array:

```
users = [
  {
    id: 2,
    name: 'name2'
  },{
    id: 2,
    name: 'name2'
  },{
    id: 3,
    name: 'name3'
  }
];

selectedUsers3 = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: 'name1'
  },{
    id: 2,
    name: 'name2'
  }
];
```

I'm facing a wired situation which is when I bind `Object` to `select options` by `[ngValue]`, and bind a function to `[selected]` which will check whether the current option exists in `selectedUsers`.

I can see the function is retrieved and the result is returned true/false as excepted, but the options keeps unselected.

template:

```
<select multiple [(ngModel)]="selectedUsers3">
  <option *ngFor="let user of users" [selected]="checkExist(user)" [ngValue]="user">{{user.name}}</option>
</select>
```

function in component:

```
checkExist(user) {
  return this.selectedUsers3.findIndex(selUser => selUser.id === user.id) > -1;
  //return this.selectedUsers3.filter(selUser => selUser.id === user.id).length > 0;
}
```

mention that I used `Array.filter` or `Array.findIndex` to check whether the data exists, and the result is correct.

Please refer this [demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/QLAnfB98o52Eqxf56Knh?p=preview) with the third `dropdownlist`, and check where am I doing something wrong? or am I missing something about `[selected]`? I hope someone can explain clearly about this.

**UPD:**

with @Günter Zöchbauer's help, this situation can be solved by using `compareWith` directive(refer his answer) no matter `single select` or `multi select`, but I'm still confused why they work well alongside but fail together and still trying to figure out the reason.

Comment: What behaviour are you expecting after the function has been called?

Comment: if the option exist in `selectedUsers` it should be selected.

Comment: Don't use `selected` along with `ngModel` according to these questions http://stackoverflow.com/a/41889504/5043867, http://stackoverflow.com/q/40730700/5043867 .... reason is still confusing to me

Comment: @PardeepJain agreed! I just figured out it may be conflicts between ngModel and selected as you said. :)

Comment: did you solved your problem ? @Pengyy

Comment: @PardeepJain no, I still need to figure this out for this feature makes selecting object complex.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`selected` is not supported with `[(ngModel)]="selectedUser3"`.

To make an item selected, the `value` (for string only) or `ngValue` property value needs to match the value in `selectedUser3`.

```
this.selectedUser3 = this.users[2];
```

By default only object identity is checked, therefore another object instance with the same properties and values doesn't match.
You can customize comparison using `compareWith`

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/forms/index/SelectControlValueAccessor-directive.html

> ```
> <select [compareWith]="compareFn"  [(ngModel)]="selectedCountries">
>     <option *ngFor="let country of countries" [ngValue]="country">
>         {{country.name}}
>     </option>
> </select>
> compareFn(c1: Country, c2: Country): boolean {
>     return c1 && c2 ? c1.id === c2.id : c1 === c2;
> }
> ```

Comment: sorry to say @gunter but it is still confusing its internal structure, would be better if you provide more detail about this

Comment: yes, this is how I'm doing with the first dropdown. but can you explain the reson for this? If we can deal it only with the object instance, after we got data from backend then we have to do filter again only to get the same instance from `users`.

Comment: The directive used for the option items doesn't read the `selected` property, it only **sets** the `selectedIndex` property. https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/5293794316cc1b0f57d5d88b3fefdf6ae29d0d97/packages/forms/src/directives/select_control_value_accessor.ts#L168

Comment: @Pengyy the `compareWith` allows to customize the comparison (see my updated answer)

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer but when i debug, I can see that the function binded to `selected` is been called.

Comment: What do you mean by "`selected` being called". That might be some browser behavior that it reflects the value to `selected` when `selectedIndex` is set.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer I just add console.log into function `checkExist` and see outputs from it.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer after read through the documentation, It seems `compareWith` doesn't support `multiple select` :(

Comment: I don't know about multiselect, I haven't used it yet myself.

Answer (score 1):

**Answer to conflicts between [(ngModel)] and [selected]**

after some research and debug, I find that while using `ngModel` on `select`, angular will run it's own **[`SelectMultipleControlValueAccessor`](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/forms/src/directives/select_multiple_control_value_accessor.ts#L78)** for `select` and own **[`directive`](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/forms/src/directives/select_multiple_control_value_accessor.ts#L179)** for `option` of `select` which lead `selected` to be **ignored**.

In the third example(example [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/QLAnfB98o52Eqxf56Knh?p=preview)), after `ngModel` is used, although function bind to `[selected]` will be called, but it's result is simply ignored.

---

**Comments**

- **comment1:**
  The problem can be solved by binding `[(ngModel)]` and `[ngValue]` with same instance of objects.
- **comment2:**
  The problem can also be solved by using `compareWith` directive, see **[Gunter' s anwser](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44045425/7579471)**
- **comment3:**
  This will happen also for single select, see **[`SelectControlValueAccessor`](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/forms/src/directives/select_control_value_accessor.ts#L98)** and **[`directive`](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/forms/src/directives/select_control_value_accessor.ts#L170)** for `option`.

---

**New Info:**

See also this [issue](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/14399) for more information.