# Angular - select placeholder not showing

Tags: html, angular

is there any reason why this simple code won't work? I'm trying to have a placeholder on my select, but it simply shows as one of the other options in the list.

```
<div *ngFor="let d of formDatiRichiesta" class="form-row">
          <select *ngIf="d.type=='select'" 
                  class="form-control" 
                  name="{{d.name}}" 
                  [(ngModel)]="model[d.name]"
                  required>
            <option selected disabled>{{d.placeholder}}</option>
            <option *ngFor="let b of elencoBanche" value="{{b.id}}">{{b.denominazione}}</option>
          </select>
        </div>
```

I'm using `angular4`. Thanks.

--EDIT--
I found out that if I delete [`(ngModel)]="model[d.name]"` all works fine. Any hint?

Comment: When you don't assign value to option, then it'll be assigned value which is the same as text, also `ngModel` will clear the selected property if your option's value doesn't match with `ngModel`.

Comment: what is 'model' ?

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44044746/selected-of-select-doesnt-work-as-excepted-in-angular2/44151189#44151189

Answer (score 7):

You have to set the value of the `<option>` to the value of the model, because the `<select>` will use the value of the model as the default selection.

When the model is undefined at the beginning you can do it like this:

`<option value="undefined">Please choose...</option>`

Answer (score 5):

That's how it is supposed to work. With the attribute`disabled` you can't choose it as an option.

But you could add the `hidden` attribute to also hide it:

```
<option value="" selected disabled hidden>{{d.placeholder}}</option>
```

Answer (score 4):

```
 <select formControlName="value"  class="form-control"
                    style=" height: 40px">
                      <option [ngValue]="null" selected disabled hidden>Select</option>
                      <option>Save</option>
                      <option>Download</option>

                    </select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this simply it will work.

```
<option value="" disabled>Select Category</option>
```

Or

```
<option [ngValue]="null">Select Category</option>
```